# React-Native-Fetch-Blob: connection was lost

Tags: ios, react-native, download, react-native-fetch-blob

I am using React-Native-Fetch-Blob and it is working fine for small files, but when I try to download an 80MB zip file it stops about 30% through and throws an error stating that the network connection was lost. The download link works everywhere else: in safari, download apps, etc. But my app I'm getting the aforementioned error. Is there something I am missing? And is there an alternative library I can use that provides download progress?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @Stophface I did tests using other libraries, and also using Objective c. It turned out that my download source was unreliable, and that there would be a lost connection despite what library I was using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!